# Disable popup on a context menu?

Tags: delphi

How can I disable popup of a popup menu?

My problem is that I have a nice context menu for my listbox but if I shift-rightclick an item, I execute some code, and I don't want the popup menu popping up afterwards.

But if it is a normal rightclick on the listbox, then of course I want the popup menu.

Comment: Handle the [`OnContextPopup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnContextPopup) event and return there True to the `Handled` parameter if you want to prevent the popup menu to be shown.

Comment: @TLama: that looks like an answer, not a comment! (And perhaps even a correct one!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>There's no "OnContextPopup" in Delphi, and no "Handled" parameter either. One way of doing this in Delphi is as follows:</strike>

Locate the PopupMenu on your form, click it, go to the events tab of the object inspector, double-click the cell to the right of "OnPopup" and insert the following code (the line right after begin):

```
PROCEDURE TForm1.PopupMenu1Popup(Sender : TObject);
  BEGIN
    IF GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) AND $8000<>0 THEN Abort
  END;
```

this will suppress the popup menu, if any of the two SHIFT keys are pressed when the menu is about to pop up...

Another way (spurred by TLama's comment above) is to locate the OnContextPopup event for the control you want to suppress the popup for (in this case your ListBox), double click it (to create/jump to the event handler) and insert the following code:

```
PROCEDURE TForm1.ListBox1ContextPopup(Sender : TObject ; Point : TPoint ; VAR Handled : BOOLEAN);
  BEGIN
    Handled:=(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) AND $8000<>0)
  END;
```

The main difference between these two methods is that the first one suppresses the popup, no matter which control the popup menu is attempting to pop up over, whereas the second method allows you to only suppress the popup for specific controls (as you can assign the same popup menu to several controls).

Comment: @TLama referred to the `TControl.OnContextPopup` itself. you could have followed the link in his comment... :)

Comment: Okay - didn't know that one (it's not a published event, so you'll have to do it in code). Updated answer to show alternate way of doing it.

Comment: "it's not a published event" - wrong. drop a TListBox and check the published events. specially on `OnContextPopup`

Comment: You're right - it is (Have overlooked it for some years - probably because of its name "Context" not having any relation to "Popup", so I have never made the connection). The name "Context" led my thoughts along the C# line, as popup menus there are called ContextMenu IIRC.

Comment: that was easy, I was looking for Handled initially but missed the OnContextPopup event since I was using the other popup event.